# Changing the numbering in appendix

Tags: numbering, counters, appendices

So I use the following theorem environments, which are resetted in each section.

```
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
```

So I have a counter for each theorem, i.e. for definition, proposition and lemma. But in the appendix, I want that definition, proposition and lemma share a counter, that is they get labeled consecutively.

In other words, after I start

```
\appendix
```

I would like to have the following numbering:
**Lemma A.1
Proposition A.2**

instead of
**Lemma A.1
Proposition A.1**

How can this be achieved? I have been trying a lot, but without success.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The following document illustrates my problem.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}



\begin{document}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]


\section{First section}
\begin{definition}
 test
\end{definition}
\begin{definition}
 test2
\end{definition}
\begin{lemma}
 testLemma
\end{lemma}


\appendix
\section{My appendix}
\begin{lemma}
 THIS IS
\end{lemma}
\begin{proposition}
 NOT THE WAY I WANT IT TO BE
\end{proposition}




\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post a full, yet minimal, compilable code?

Comment: Sure, added it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy with `ntheorem` which has a `\renewtheorem` command and `apptools`, for its `\AtAppendix` command:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\usepackage{apptools}
\AtAppendix{\renewtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\renewtheorem{proposition}[definition]{Proposition}
\renewtheorem{lemma}[definition]{Lemma}}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
\begin{definition}
  test.
\end{definition}
\begin{definition}
  test2.
\end{definition}
\begin{lemma}
  test Lemma.
\end{lemma}

\appendix

\section{My appendix}

\begin{lemma}
  THIS IS
\end{lemma}
\begin{proposition}
  NOT THE WAY I WANT IT TO BE
\end{proposition}

\begin{definition}
  OR IS IT?
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]